# Event Listeners of elements are removed after pushed content are restored from window.history

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener

I am trying to push the content of a tag using window.pushState and then `onpopstate` I am restoring the content into the tag. But after I restored the content of the tag, none of the elements inside the tag had any Event Listener with them. How can I store the content of a tag with all the event listeners associated with them?

Here's the code that pushes the `innerHTML` of a main:

```
const main = document.getElementById("main");

const push_main = (title = document.title, url = window.location.href) => {
    let main_html= main.innerHTML;
    document.title = title;
    window.history.pushState({"main_html": main_html), "doc_title": title }, "", url);

}
```

and then `onpopstate` the stored `innerHTML` of the main tag is put into it again:

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    if (e.state) {
        main.innerHTML = e.state.main_html;
        document.title = e.state.doc_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: why can’t you reattach event listeners after updating the inner HTML? You just run the same logic as you do when the page is first loaded. Alternatively if you’re only listening to events that can bubble, consider listening to those events bubbles up to a parent element that is always present on the page.

Comment: You can delegate the event listener to the body via document.body and just check to see what was clicked and run the appropriate functions. This will always exist no matter what gets added, updated and removed. So it will be consistent